# Restructure nested JSON data

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "filaria": [{
        "user_input_test_result": "",
        "test_id": "3519710705971061481279327210",
        "gid": "1481279304461"
    }, {
        "user_input_test_result": "",
        "test_id": "3519710705971061481279364547",
        "gid": "1481279342277"
    }],
    "patient_test_analysis": [{

        "test_id": "3519710705971061481279327210",
        "gid": "1481279304461"

    }, {
        "test_id": "3519710705971061481279364547",
        "gid": "1481279342277"

    }]
}
```

I have to restructure this JSON on the basis of key name `gid` so that the `filaria` and `patient_test_analysis` data become sub-arrays of the corresponding `gid` value, like this:

```
{
    "upload_status": {
        "1481279304461": {
            "filaria": [{
                "status": "Success",
                "test_id": "3519710705971061481279327210"
            }],
            "patient_test_analysis": [{
                "status": "Success",
                "test_id": "3519710705971061481279327210"
            }]
        },
        "1481279342277": {
            "filaria": [{
                "status": "Success",
                "test_id": "3519710705971061481279364547"
            }],
            "patient_test_analysis": [{
                "status": "Success",
                "test_id": "3519710705971061481279364547"
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Each sub-array must also have a `"status": "Success"` element added.

---

I wrote following code to get the output:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
$arrayStatus = array();

foreach ($jsonArray as $key => $value) {
    $key; $inc = 0 ;
    for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++){ 
        $patient_id = $value[$i]['gid'];
        $s = $inc++;
        $arrayStatus[$patient_id][$key][$s]['status'] = "Success";
        $arrayStatus[$patient_id][$key][$s]['test_id'] = 'xxx';     
    }     
}         

$results = array();    
$results['upload_status'] = $arrayStatus; 
echo $resArr = json_encode($results);
```

but I get following output:

```
{
    "upload_status": {
        "1481279304461": {
            "filaria": [{
                "status": "Success",
                "test_id": "3519710705971061481279327210"
            }],
            "patient_test_analysis": [{
                "status": "Success",
                "test_id": "3519710705971061481279327210"
            }]
        },
        "1481279342277": {
            "filaria": {
                "1": {
                    "status": "Success",
                    "test_id": "3519710705971061481279364547"
                }
            },
            "patient_test_analysis": {
                "1": {
                    "status": "Success",
                    "test_id": "3519710705971061481279364547"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with an extra level of indirection in the second `gid`.

I don't know where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);

$arrayStatus = array();


foreach ($jsonArray as $key => $value) {

    $key; $inc = 0 ;
    for($i=0;$i<count($value);$i++){

        $patient_id = $value[$i]['gid'];
        $s = $inc++;
        //Avoid array indexs
        $arrayStatus[$patient_id][$key][] = ['status' => "Success", 'test_id' => 'xxx'];

    }
}

$results = array();
$results['upload_status'] = $arrayStatus;
echo $resArr = json_encode($results);
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.!! can you explain lit bit more why u use big bracket in Key and value.